# Proof That For Two Uncountable Sets, The Cardinality of the Collection of Their Respective Uncountable Subsets Are Equal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The proposition I came along is as follows:

Assume $S$ & $T$ are uncountable sets. Then if $\mathcal{P}_{u}(S)$ and $\mathcal{P}_{u}(T)$ denotes the respective collection of uncountable subsets of $S$ & $T$,  $|\mathcal{P}_{u}(S)| = |\mathcal{P}_{u}(T)|$.

I did write out a proof on if $|S| = |T|$, then $|\mathcal{P}(S)| = |\mathcal{P}(T)|$ for the normal type of Power sets. This conclusion was derived from the fact that due to the existence of bijective function, $f: S \rightarrow T$, and $f^{-1}: T \rightarrow S$, all sets within each power set can be constructed by a mapping from a set $S_{i} \rightarrow T_{i}$ s.t. $S_{i} \subseteq S$ and $T_{i} \subseteq T$. However, the likely apparent connection between this proof and the former is still uncertain for myself.

Comment: If this were true, then $2^{\omega_1}$ would be the greatest cardinal.

Comment: @Brian: I would have thought that $2^{\aleph_0}$ would have been the largest cardinal...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, I was thinking: given any $\kappa$, if $\kappa=\aleph_0$ then $\kappa < 2^{\aleph_1}$, so assume $\kappa$ uncountable; thus $\kappa < 2^{\kappa} = 2^{\aleph_1}$. Corollary: every cardinal is $< 2^{\aleph_1}$. Including  $2^{\aleph_1}$ itself. ¶ Not sure how you bound everything by $ 2^{\aleph_0}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is wildly not true. Take $T$ to be any uncountable set, you can show that $|\mathcal P(T)|=|\mathcal P_u(T)|$. Now take $S$ to be $\mathcal P(T)$ and disprove the claim.

(Even without this additional claim, you can directly show this is false for $T$ any uncountable set and $S=\mathcal P(\mathcal P(T))$.)

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks. However, how do you show: $|\mathcal{P}_{u}(S)| = |\mathcal{P}(T)|$?

Comment: You should use the fact that $|T|=|T\times T|$, and that $T$ is uncountable.

Comment: Note: you need the axiom of choice to show $\vert\mathcal{P}(T)\vert=\vert\mathcal{P}_u(T)\vert$ for uncountable $T$, but that's a very minor quibble.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, but as far as concrete counterexamples go you can find things that work even without choice.